# Launching process to open local html file results in Access Denied

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to open a local HTML file in the default web browser using C# and UWP.

```
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Users\Julie\source\repos\QuoteTool\QuoteTool\Assets\quote-pdf.html");
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info);
```

I tried running the documention on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netframework-4.8 , with the code resulting in 'Access Denied'.

Have also tried running Visual Studio as Administrator (same result)

Any guidance would be very helpful!!! I'm tearing my hair out!

Comment: Which one results in 'Access Denied'? The documentation code, or your three-line C# code? Have you tried `UseShellExecute = true`? Is there any reason you want `UseShellExecute = false`?

Answer (score 0):

Base on this code `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string, string)` first parameter means what you want and second means where you want so probably it can help you to solve your problem.Please see this document [Process.Start Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_System_String_)

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR") + @"\explorer.exe", pathToFolder);
```